# Out of range when converting data SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion

I have a `varchar` column with string like date `dd.mm.yyyy` and I need it to convert to same string only with different format like `yyyy.mm.ddT00:00:000`

SOLVED: 1st Test:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(table.DATE AS datetime), 126),'-','.') AS date 
FROM tabletest.DBO.TABLE
```

Result:

I get 5 values (from more than 1000) and msg:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

SOLVED: 2nd Test:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, (RIGHT(GREMPG1.DAT,4)+SUBSTRING(GREMPG1.DAT,3,4)+LEFT(GREMPG1.DAT, 2) + ), 126),'-','.') AS Datums 
FROM tabletest.DBO.GREMPG1
```

Cannot find solution on how to get second part to this.

Maybe there is some shortest way yo convert columns record format?

Thanks.

Edited:

For second query:

- Old value: 01.03.2014
- New value: 2014.03.01
- Need to get: 2014.03.01T00:00:00

Comment: Post some sample data please

Comment: So you need output as varchar or in a date format?

Comment: Try using `datetime2` instead of `datetime`. Former can store the dates which are out of range for `datetime`

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server? How many rows do you have? I suppose that one of the strings is wrong. For example: `30.02.2012`. Or the convertion is not correct trying to convert `15.02.2012` as `mm.dd.yyyy`

Comment: DhruvJoshi: It depend.. Most important to me is to get right format at the end. DateTime2 is showing message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Bogdan: Both are written in sql server. I have 4270 rows. First sql gives me only first 5 results, 2nd one gives me all results, but only first part (date in yyyy.mm.dd)

Comment: @elly, as I suggested in my answer "only the  first 5 results" could mean, that the sixth row carries bad data... Or that your system takes mm.dd instead of dd.mm

Comment: 5th and 6th row data are the same. But with first one sql is ok for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first test try this way -

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime,table.DATE,103), 126),'-','.') AS date FROM tabletest.DBO.TABLE
```

For your 2nd try -

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST((RIGHT(GREMPG1.DAT,4)+SUBSTRING(GREMPG1.DAT,3,4)+LEFT(GREMPG1.DAT, 2)) AS DATETIME), 126),'-','.') AS Datums FROM tabletest.DBO.GREMPG1
```

Comment: Great! This worked. I wrote in this way previosly, but didn't get result. Thanks.

Comment: How about 2nd sql? Some options on how to finish/continiue/change to get working with LEFT/RIGHT/SUBSTRING?

Comment: @elly - your source stores only `dd.mm.yyyy`, so when you try to convert to `yyyy.mm.ddT00:00:000` the time part will always give you zero is that right? In that case just append the `T00:00:000` after your 2nd query.

Comment: Logically. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime,'15.02.2012',104), 126),'-','.') AS date
```

You get confision with the date when you cast. `15.02.2012` is calculated as `mm.dd.yyyy` and because there is not month 15 you get error.

So you query will look like:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime,table.DATE,104), 126),'-','.') AS date 
FROM 
    tabletest.DBO.TABLE;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this worked for me. Previsoly did in this way, but without results.

Comment: Any ideas on 2nd one?

Comment: No, post your original query.

Comment: It is orginal. I dont have anything else. I need to get same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT seems to work. Try this:

```
declare @d VARCHAR(100)='13.12.2015';
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(@d AS datetime), 126),'-','.') AS date
/*
Result: 2015.12.13T00:00:00
*/
```

If it does NOT work, I'd assume a culture issue (date formats are handled quite differently according to your system's language and country).

If it works, I'd assume at least one value in your db being bad...